# Set Datetimepicker to a date from a string

Tags: c#

I got a file which has dates stored as the following format (yyyy|dMM|dd). I now need to retrieve the values from this file and set the datetimepicker to the correct year month and day matching the ones in the stored string. Im able to retrieve all data correctly only i dont know how to set the calander correctly matching the strings. This is what i got so far although it doesnt work:

```
string[] editdate = clean[3].Split('|');
EditDatepickCalendar.Value = DateTime.Parse("{0},{1},{2}", editdate[0], editdate[1], editdate[2]);
```

Comment: Did you try `DateTime.ParseExact` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If sounds like you should just be using `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(clean[3], "yyyy'|'MM'|'dd",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Quoting the `|` isn't strictly necessary here, but it makes it clear that you're just intending them to be taken as literal text, rather than having any date/time-related meaning.

(Note that the problem really isn't anything to do with the `DateTimePicker` here - it's parsing the value. When you run into an issue, you should perform appropriate diagnostics to work out where it is - in the UI, data tranformation, storage etc.)

Comment: First param in `ParseExact` shouldn't be date (as string) and second format?

Answer (score 1):

Check like this, some times DateTime.Parse will through an excepiton.... See below code part,

```
            string DateString = "2012|01|01";
            dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "yyyy|MM|dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: Gives me a "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime", string is currently editdate = 2012|01|01

Comment: Works flawless, something was going wrong at retrieving the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(
    clean[3], 
    "yyyy|MM|dd", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```